# Filter series show on Power Bi Line Chart

Tags: powerbi

I'm encountering a problem with one of my Power Bi visuals. I have a line chart that's created from a table like below. I'd like to give users the option of filtering out Projects(lines) however I cant get my slicer to interact with the visual. I've checked the 'edit interactions' and its showing they are linked. Can anyone assist?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power Query you will need to [unpivot your table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column) so that the table structure becomes:

| Month | Project | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | Project 1 | 45 |
| Jan | Project 2 | 30 |
| Jan | Project 3 | 50 |
| Feb | Project 1 | 47 |
| Feb | Project 2 | 36 |
| Feb | Project 3 | 47 |
| Mar | Project 1 | 51 |
| Mar | Project 2 | 38 |
| Mar | Project 3 | 43 |

Then you will be able to use the `Project` column for filters/slicers/legends.